# Cucumber fails during @before hook : NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber, chrome-web-driver

Automation framework won't proceed in executing steps at .feature file after Chrome browser was opened (then just closes after)

GenericStepImplementation.java Codes

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws ConfigurationException, org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.ChromeDriver","C:\\Automation\\Webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    config = new XMLConfiguration("sample-object-config.xml");
}
```

RunAutoTest.java Codes

```
package test_runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
glue={"code_bindings"},
features="src/test/resources/features", 
plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report"})

public class RunAutoTest {

}
```

Sample.feature

```
Feature: Automation Test

@Login-Successful
Scenario: Login (Successful)
Given I go to "www.yahoo.com" URL
    Then I enter "m@yahoo.com" into "login.username" field and click tab
    Then I enter "1234567890" into "login.password" text field
    Then I clicked on "login.loginlink" login button
    Then I wait for "15" seconds
    And I will capture the page named "Login-Successful"
```

After running as JUnit Test, Chrome browser was opened but doesn't execute steps in Sample.feature file. Console also displays:

```
*Feature: Automation Test
Starting ChromeDriver 2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387) on port 11795
Only local connections are allowed.
Jan 07, 2019 6:00:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
[31mFailure in before hook:[0m[31mGenericStepImplementation.setUp()[0m
[31mMessage: [0m[31mjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration.constructHierarchy(XMLConfiguration.java:640)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration.constructHierarchy(XMLConfiguration.java:635)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration.initProperties(XMLConfiguration.java:596)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration.load(XMLConfiguration.java:1009)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration.load(XMLConfiguration.java:972)
```

Comment: It seems you are missing the apache commons collection library. You could try adding that to your build .

Comment: You can get the library from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-collections/commons-collections as for adding it to your build that depends on what you are using (maven, gradle, etc)

Comment: @CalvinIyer i have downloaded commons-collections4-4.2 jar and added to java build path. still it isn't working. any other suggestion?

Comment: you need the `commons-collection` instead of the `commons-collection4` library as per the error above.

Comment: @CalvinIyer wait.. will i still be downloading commons-collection jar file just to add to java build path?

Comment: Yes but its a different version of the library. Commons 4 is the newer iteration which is not what you need to fix the error.

Comment: @CalvinIyer yes. i have downloaded commons-collections-3 and it's now working! thank you so much for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the keyword within the `System.setProperty` line from `ChromeDriver` to **`driver`** i.e. change:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.ChromeDriver","C:\\Automation\\Webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
```

To:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Automation\\Webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
                             only ^^^driver^^^
```

Comment: it didn't work. just same results. :( any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html

This exception happens when the class existed during compilation, but doesn't exist in runtime.

Please ensure that your classpath contains `org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils`. Probably library `commons-collections` is absent in classpath.

Comment: i have downloaded commons-collections4-4.2 jar and added to java build path. still it isn't working. any other suggestion?

Comment: I see you've found the answer above. Happy for you! 

Answer (score -1):

Just change the 
`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.ChromeDriver","C:\\Automation\\Webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe");`

Comment: change to what?